# How to solve kivy error: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Tags: python, kivy, spinner, attributeerror

I am new in kivy, I created a form that uses 2 spinner, the 1st spinner contain a list of values that when selected it will call a function from .py file and change the values of the 2nd spinner. But whenever i select a value from the 1st spinner the **"AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'"** is displayed.
I've tried so many things but couldn't make it work, Please any attempt is appreciate.

**My .py file:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

#dummy screen
class Blank(Screen):
    def on_enter(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.change_screen)
    def change_screen(self, dt):
        if True: self.manager.current = 'page1'
        else: self.manager.current = 'menu'
        
class Page1(Screen):
    combinations_id = ObjectProperty(None)
    def spinner_func(self):
        self.ids.combinations.values = ['g','y']
    
class Menu(Screen):
    pass
    
class Profile(Screen):
    pass

class MainMenu(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file('main.kv')

class SpinApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.other = Page1()
        return kv
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    SpinApp().run()
```

** this is .kv file:**

```
MainMenu:
    Blank:
    Page1:
    Menu:
    Profile:


<Menu>:
    name: 'menu'
    Label:
        text: 'MENU'
<Profile>:
    name: 'profile'
    Label:
        text: 'profile'

<Page1>:
    name: 'page1'
    BoxLayout:
        combinations_id: combinations_id
        orientation: 'vertical'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: (253/255, 245/255, 230/255, 1)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
    
        Label:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: (250/255, 235/255, 210/255, 1)
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            color: 47/255, 79/255, 79/255, 1
            text: 'please fill the form for conveniency'
            font_size: 34
            italic: True
            bold: True
            size_hint_y: 0.18
        
        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                size: root.width, root.height
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 1200
                width: self.minimum_width
                rows: 3
                cols: 1
                spacing: 10
                    
                RelativeLayout:
                    Label:
                        text: 'User Profile'
                        size_hint: (0.45,None)
                        height: 100
                        font_size: 30
                        bold: True
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.332}
                        canvas.before:
                            Color:
                                rgb: (43/255, 88/255, 108/255, 1)
                            RoundedRectangle:
                                size: self.size
                                pos: self.pos
                                radius: [15]
                    
                    #form layout
                RelativeLayout:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 900
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: (root.width)*0.8
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
                        padding: [15,10,10,0]
                        canvas:
                            Color:
                                rgb: (93/255, 138/255, 168/255, 1)
                            RoundedRectangle:
                                size: self.size
                                pos: self.pos
                                radius: [20,20,20,20]
                                    
                        Label:
                            id: name
                            text: '\nName'
                            size_hint_x: None
                            size: self.texture_size
                            pos_hint: {'left': 1}
                            bold: True
                        Input_text:
                            hint_text: 'eg. AbdulAzeez Nuhu'
                                
                        Input_label:
                            text: '\nMatric Number'
                        Input_text:
                            hint_text: 'eg. se/mat-csc/19/0000'
                                
                        Input_label:
                            text: '\nSchool'
                        My_spinner:
                            id: schools_id
                            text: 'Choose your school'
                            values: ['Science', 'Education', 'Vocational', 'Technical', 'Art and Sos', 'Languages']
                            on_text: app.other.spinner_func()
                                
                        Input_label:
                            text: '\nCombination'
                        My_spinner:
                            id: combinations_id
                            text: 'Choose your Combination'
                            values: []
                            on_text: root.comb_func()
                            
                        Input_label:
                            text: '\nLevel'
                        GridLayout:
                            cols: 7
                            GridLayout:
                                cols: 2
                                CheckBox:
                                    group: 'level'
                                Label:
                                    text: '100' 
                            Label:
                                size_hint_x: 0.3
                                    
                            GridLayout:
                                cols: 2
                                CheckBox:
                                    group: 'level'
                                Label:
                                    text: '200' 
                            Label:
                                size_hint_x: 0.3
                                    
                            GridLayout:
                                cols: 2
                                CheckBox:
                                    group: 'level'
                                Label:
                                    text: '300'
                            Label:
                                size_hint_x: 1.5
                    
                RelativeLayout:
                    Round_Button:
                        text: 'Submit'
                        size_hint: (0.8, None)
                        height: 100
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'top':1}
                        on_release: app.root.current = 'menu'
        
<Input_label@Label>:
    size_hint_x: None
    size: self.texture_size
    pos_hint: {'left': 1,}
    bold: True
    
<Input_text@TextInput>:
    multiline: False
    size_hint_y: 0.8
    padding: [10, 10]
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: 240/255, 248/255, 1, 1
    valign: 'bottom'
    
<My_spinner@Spinner>:
    color: 0.5,0.5,0.5,1
    size_hint_y: 0.8
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'left'
    padding: [15,15]
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: 240/255, 248/255, 1, 1

<SpinnerOption>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 70
    color: 1,1,1,1
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'left'
    padding_x: 15
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: 112/255, 128/255, 144/255, 1

<Round_Button@Button>:
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: (0, 123/255, 167/255, 1) if self.state=='normal' else (0,.7,.7,1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [20,20,20,20]
```

**output:**

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /storage/emulated/0/kivi/.kivy/logs/kivy_21-05-12_22.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.3 (default, Jun 15 2020, 02:19:10) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 2.0'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ARM'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mali-400 MP'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 860, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'combinations'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/storage/emulated/0/kivi/newfile5.py", line 41, in <module>
     SpinApp().run()
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 342, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 293, in post_dispatch_input
     wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
     self.dispatch('on_release')
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1138, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/spinner.py", line 196, in <lambda>
     item.bind(on_release=lambda option: dp.select(option.text))
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/dropdown.py", line 275, in select
     self.dispatch('on_select', data)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1138, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/spinner.py", line 213, in _on_dropdown_select
     self.text = data
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 497, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 544, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 599, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1096, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "/storage/emulated/0/kivi/main.kv", line 108, in <module>
     on_text: app.other.spinner_func()
   File "/storage/emulated/0/kivi/newfile5.py", line 21, in spinner_func
     self.ids.combinations.values = ['g','y']
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to reference a non-existent `id` in the line:

```
self.ids.combinations.values = ['g','y']
```

I believe the `id` that you are trying to reference is `combinations_id`.
Try changing that line to:

```
self.ids.combinations_id.values = ['g', 'y']
```

Also, in your `build()` method, the line:

```
self.other = Page1()
```

is creating a new instance of `Page1`, but that instance is not the one that is displayed in your GUI, so that line can be removed. Then. in your `kv`, change the line:

```
on_text: app.other.spinner_func()
```

to:

```
on_text: root.spinner_func()
```

Comment: Wow! It really work, the error disappear but the 2nd spinner values doesn't change. Please how to change it. Thank u

Comment: Thanks a lot bro!